# Is dbContext.SaveChanges() enough to save all 3 operations, insert, update and delete for multiple tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

```
//Say I have below lists:
List<Table1> table1InsertLines;
List<Table1> table1UpdateLinesFromDbContext;//(DbContext.Table1 lines are updated)
List<Table2> table2DeleteLines;
List<Table2> table2InsertLines;
List<Table2> table2UpdateLinesFromDbContext;//(DbContext.Table1 lines are updated)
List<Table1> table1DeleteLines;
//And I do below steps
dbContext.Table1.AddRange(table1InsertLines);
dbContext.Table1.RemoveRange(table2DeleteLines);
dbContext.Table2.AddRange(table1InsertLines);
dbContext.Table2.RemoveRange(table2DeleteLines);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Is this enough to ensure consistency given that SaveChanges is a transaction itself?

Comment: Yes, the DbContext will keep track of `all` the changes and ensure to call the Insert, Update and Delete queries when `Savechanges` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DbContext will keep track of all the changes and ensure to call the Insert, Update and Delete queries when Savechanges is invoked.